# Compiling Java 11 Application with Java 12 SDK- Which version of java is my application?

Tags: java

As the title says. I am using the Java 12 SDK compiling down to a Java 11 Application. When I compile down like this, is it still using the new garbage collector of Java 12, or does it get downgraded to whatever Java 11 is using?

Edit: Updated my question to avoid "JRE"

Comment: *"Compiling Java 11 JRE .... "* - Are you talking about building a JRE or a Java application?

Comment: @StephenC Java application

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collector is an implementation detail of the JRE / JVM. If you run a Java 11 JRE, your program will run with the garbage collector of that JRE. Simple as that.

Note that you can never know at compile time which garbage collector will be used at runtime because even within Java 12, there are multiple JVM implementations (Oracle Hotspot, IBM), each with multiple garbage collection algorithms, whose behavior can be configured at startup. Thus you should not rely on any behavior of the garbage collector, aside from the fact that it collects garbage.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know, at compile time, what Java runtime your application will be running with.  It sounds like you're compiling your application, *not* the JRE, with something equivalent to the `--release 11` flag to `javac`.

This means that you can run the compiled application with a Java 11 runtime.  But you could also run the application with a Java 12 runtime.

---

EDIT: To elaborate a bit, when compiling to native code you compile to a specific architecture, say x64, but you don't know what specific machine your application will be executed on.  It may eventually be executed on a machine that does not exist yet.

In the same way, the Java compiler emits bytecode that is compatible with a given version of the JVM, and subsequent versions are backwards compatible.  So if you target Java 11 bytecode you can run your application on JVM 11 or any later version that is compatible with that version of the bytecode.

The JVM is *not* included with your compiled application.  If Java 22 has some fancy new garbage collector and I run your application, that was compiled to Java 11 bytecode, on JVM 22, it will use that new garbage collector.